# A question relating to citation of papers.

Tags: research

I am reading a paper: "A geometric setting for the quantum deformation of $GL_n$", how to find some other papers that quoted from this article?

I would appreciate it if you could give me some suggestions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Type the article in on google scholar and then click the "Cited by X" link to see all the papers that cited this work.

Comment: @twnly Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It would be helpful if the answer was posted as an Answer—so it can be accepted and the question doesn't sit around on the Unanswered Questions list forever.